# Is there something faster than a WHERE IN clause in postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I'm working with .net core 3.1

And i'm using the postgres Npgsql package.

In this case, i have a table called `messages` on the database. 
I want to get the rows from table that meet a certain condition, which is the id from those rows need to be contained on an array/list i provide.

The table can have thousands of results, and the `ids` can contain up to 1000 values.

An example is:

`ids is a List<long>`

```
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM \"messages\" WHERE id IN ({string.Join(",", ids)});", conn))
        {
            long key;
            MessagesJson val;
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                key = Int64.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                var content = reader[1].ToString();
                val = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MessagesJson>(content);
                messages.Add(new Message<long, MessagesJson>() { Key = key, Value = val });
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

This code works well, my question is, if there is a faster way of doing this than `WHERE id IN ({string.Join(",", ids)})`?

Or i maybe doing something unrelated to the question that may as well be of poor performance. Thanks.

The version of postgres used is 11.

Comment: If you have poor performance then it is likely on the DB side, not the C# side.

Comment: Do you have an index on `messages.id`? You could try loading the `ids` into a table and doing a `join`.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?  Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the query.

Comment: Hi @NetMage, someone told me about creating a temp table and do a join, i don't know if you mean the same. How can i find more information about that?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, the version of postgres is 11, you mean i should explain more about the provided/intended code?

Comment: If you run the query prefixed with the string `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` it will give you info on how it ex ecuted the query.  You will have to somehow obtain the text of the query after the substitutions have been done on it, and then run it in something like `psql`.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the array as an array instead of string-concatenating it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ANY (@arrayParam)
```

However, at the end of the day you're forcing PG to go over the entire table and check every ID against your array - that's an inherently slow operation.

If you reuse the same array values, it may be worth inserting the values into a temporary table instead of resending it to the database with each query, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a contextual and tricky thing. Here's a short subset of the many things that could affect/resolve your issue:

- how slow is it now and how much faster do you need it to be?
- what are the ids ultimately used for? Do they completely exit the system? Are they used again for another query somewhere else?
- how static/dynamic is the messages table? how are messages distributed/accessed?
- how is the database configured, how was the query executed? Is the DB looking up every single value individually or is it doing a single index scan of the table? EXPLAIN ANALYZE?
- Play with the CAP theorem -- if you need it faster than normal, maybe you can relax consistency requirements?